# subplots not working properly

Tags: plotting

I have 4 plots and would like to make it a single plot. Hence I used Graphics grid command. I have a normal plot, 2 region plot and a plot3d plot. 
I used the command

```
p1 = GraphicsGrid[{{deltalimit, radiallimit3dKM}, {regionMax, 
     regionK}}, ImageSize -> Scaled[[2]];
```

[image]

You can see that the 3D plot is very small and all other plots comes out nicely. How to rectify this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mathematica is not very good with grids of plots. I suggest using `Grid` instead of `GraphicsGrid` as the first try. Then you can adjust the size of the subplots individually (with an explicit ImageSize option for each). To make nice plot grids, try [SciDraw](https://scidraw.nd.edu/). It has a learning curve though, and handling the colour bar may be some trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. The grid is also showing the same problem.